# How to remove carriage returns from string but leave line feeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a huge String containing many many lines and there are several lines inluding a carrieage return which shouldnt be there! I want to remove the carriage returns and leave the line feeds!

I alread tryed this:

```
string.gsub "\r", ""
```

But it didnt do anything!

// Your right I had another problem that was related to this sry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the destructive version of the method to actually modify the variable `string`.

```
string.gsub! "\r", ""
```

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
[1] pry(main)> str = "a\n\rb\nc\rd\n\ne\r\r"
=> "a\n\rb\nc\rd\n\ne\r\r"
[2] pry(main)> str.gsub("\r", "")
=> "a\nb\ncd\n\ne"
```